# How to find an item in a dbset using linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, asynchronous, dbset

I am using C# and would like some help to write a `LINQ FindAsync` statement to find a `MapLocation` with a specific `id`.

I have a `DbSet<MapCompany>`, where each `MapCompany` has a `List<MapLocation>`.

I have the `id` of the `MapLocation`, and need to write a `LINQ` statement to find the `MapLocation`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
MapLocation maplocation = await db.mapCompanies.SelectMany(mapCompany => mapCompany.mapLocations).FindAsync(id);
```

Can I please have some help to write this correctly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that code not working? What happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FindAsync()` is a method on `DbSet<T>`. `SelectMany()` returns an `IQueryable<T>` so `FindAsync()` is not available. You have to use `SingleAsync()` (or `FirstAsync()` if there's a possibility of duplicates)...

```
MapLocation maplocation = await db.mapCompanies
                                  .SelectMany(mapCompany => mapCompany.mapLocations)
                                  .SingleAsync(l => l.Id == id);
```

If you want to use `FindAsync()`, you'd have to create a `DbSet<MapLocation>` in your DbContext that maps to the `MapLocations` table. Then you can just use...

```
MapLocation maplocation = await db.MapLocations.FindAsync(id);
```